# Problemas com modelagem de dados com Persistence.xml

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, hibernate, java-ee

Criei uma aplicação da faculdade para criar tabelas automáticas pelo Hibernate com JPA

porém deu erro em algumas tabelas, que foram essas;

CatalogDAO

OrderDAO

ProductDAO

porém esta gerando o seguinte erro,

quando eu clico em  CatalogDAO gera esse erro;

```
        catalog0_.CATALOG_ID=?
20:07:25.347 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
20:07:25.347 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
20:07:25.359 [main] DEBUG o.h.l.e.p.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader - Done entity load : com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog#1
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog with id 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog_$$_jvst9c4_9.getCatalogName(Catalog_$$_jvst9c4_9.java)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.CatalogDAO.main(CatalogDAO.java:16)
```

quando tento executar essa classe OrderDAO gerra esse outro erro;

```
   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
20:09:08.829 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (BILLED_AMOUNT, BILLING_INFO_ADDR_LINE_1, BILLING_INFO_ADDR_LINE_2, BILLIN' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789) [hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.OrderDAO.salvar(OrderDAO.java:97) [classes/:na]
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.OrderDAO.main(OrderDAO.java:34) [classes/:na]
20:09:08.830 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
20:09:08.830 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (BILLED_AMOUNT, BILLING_INFO_ADDR_LINE_1, BILLING_INFO_ADDR_LINE_2, BILLIN' at line 1
20:09:08.831 [main] DEBUG o.h.j.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Mark transaction for rollback
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.OrderDAO.salvar(OrderDAO.java:97)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.OrderDAO.main(OrderDAO.java:34)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (BILLED_AMOUNT, BILLING_INFO_ADDR_LINE_1, BILLING_INFO_ADDR_LINE_2, BILLIN' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 23 more
```

e na classe ProductDAO gera esse erro;

```
20:10:32.217 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
20:10:32.217 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
20:10:32.236 [main] DEBUG o.h.l.e.p.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader - Done entity load : com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog#1
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog with id 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog_$$_jvstb59_9.getCatalogID(Catalog_$$_jvstb59_9.java)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.ProductDAO.salvar(ProductDAO.java:44)
    at com.accenture.extremeex.dao.ProductDAO.main(ProductDAO.java:25)
```

alguem pode me ajudas? as outras tabelas foram criadas menos essas classe

o código está aqui.

https://github.com/wladyband/extreme/tree/master/ExtremeEX

Answer (score 2):

A causa do erro nas classes "CatalogDAO" e "ProductDAO" é a mesma: `Unable to find com.accenture.extremeex.domain.Catalog with id 1.` Na tabela "catalog" não existe nenhum registro com CATALOG_ID igual à 1.

A causa do erro na classe "OrderDAO" é o nome da tabela "order", pois "order" é uma palavra reservada do SQL. Você pode renomear a tabela ou usar "order" entre aspas duplas. Neste segundo caso altere a anotação na classe "Order" para:
`@Entity(name="\"order\"")`